# How to check if class values are the same

Tags: jquery, forms

I want to use jQuery to not allow a form to be submitted if two form items with the same class have the same value. However, I can't get it to work. Here's what I've been trying:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myform").submit(function(){
        var tempvar;
        var count;
        var start = 0;
        var legit = true;
        $(".inputclass").each(function(index){
            count = 0;
            tempvar = this.val();
            $(".inputclass").each(function(index){
                if (tempvar == $(this).val()){
                    count++;
                }
            });

            if (count > 1){
                legit=false;
            }
        });
        return legit;       
    });     
});
```

The form will submit regardless of whether two of the values are the same, and I can't seem to work out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is below:

```
tempvar = this.val();
```

Replace this with

```
tempvar = $(this).val();
```

Hope this will help !!

Answer (score 0):

You can't just compare the new input value with the last one if there are more than two inputs, but can easily write your class values into an array and for each value check if it already exists in the array and act accordingly:

sample code:

```
var list = new Array();

$(".inputclass").each(function(index){
    var inputValue = $(this).val();
    if(inArray(inputValue, list)!= -1)
        list.push(inputValue);
    else
        alert("Value "+inputValue+" already exists!");
});
```

Comment: why do you not use brackets for the if-else? just curious.. Is it because you find it more readable, or because you have to type less, or because it's less code?

Comment: @myfunkyside, well that is OK for conditions with one instructions inside! but you can yet ALWAYS use brackets for conditions! ;)

Comment: that's why I'm asking, it couldn't be out of habit, since once you have more than one line of code you'll need those brackets anyway. So why do YOU do it? (And many other people, but you can really only answer for yourself)